# Poker Game Results Between Two Players

Tags: c

I'm at the point where I'm trying to rank my players in the game, and determine the winner.  You can read my code below, as I think I've documented the logic pretty well throughout.

What I need to do now is determine which player wins, given that there are two players.  I've laid out functions for shuffling, dealing, and determining which type of hand it is.

```
    //
//  main.c
//  Created by gixx88 on 7/22/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 gixx88. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SUITS 4
#define FACES 13
#define CARDS 52

#define HAND 5
#define PLAYERS 2

//prototypes for shuffle and deal
void shuffle( size_t wDeck[][FACES] ); //shuffling modifies wDeck
void deal( size_t wDeck[][FACES], const char *wFace[],
          const char *wSuit[] ); //dealing doesn't modify the arrays
void dealHand(size_t wHands[][HAND], size_t wDeck[][FACES]);

//prototypes for determing suit and face
size_t determineSuit(size_t wCard);
size_t determineFace(size_t wCard);


//prototypes for determing poker hand
unsigned int findAPair(size_t wHand[HAND]);
unsigned int findTwoPairs(size_t wHand[HAND]);
unsigned int findThreeOfAKind(size_t wHand[HAND]);
unsigned int findFourOfAKind(size_t wHand[HAND]);
unsigned int findFlush(size_t wHand[HAND]);
unsigned int findFullHouse(size_t wHand[HAND]);
unsigned int findStraightFlush(size_t wHand[HAND]);
unsigned int findStraight (size_t wHand[HAND]);

//prototypes for determing player outcomes
unsigned int determingPlayerHand(size_t wHand[HAND]);
void playerRank( size_t wHands[PLAYERS][HAND]);



int main(void) {

   //initialize suit array
    const char *suit[SUITS] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };

    //initilize face array
    const char *face[ FACES ] = { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
        "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

    //initilize deck array
    size_t deck[ SUITS ][FACES] = {{0}};

    size_t hands[PLAYERS][HAND] = {{0}};

    srand(time(NULL));  //random seed generator

    shuffle(deck); //shuffle the deck
    dealHand(hands, deck);

    playerRank(hands);



} //end main

//determine suit
size_t determineSuit(size_t wCard){
    return wCard / SUITS;
} // end determine suit

//determine face
size_t determineFace(size_t wCard){
    return wCard % FACES;
}//end determine face

//if four of a kind

//shuffle cards in deck
void shuffle( size_t wDeck[][FACES] ){
    size_t row; //row number
    size_t column; //column number
    size_t card; //counter

    for (card = 0; card <= CARDS; ++card){

        //choose a random location until unoccupied slot found
        do {
            row = rand() % SUITS;
            column = rand() % FACES;
        } //end do
        while (wDeck[row][column] != 0); //end do while

        //place card number in chosen slot of deck
        wDeck[row][column] = card;
    }// end for
} //end shuffle function

//deal cards in deck
void deal( size_t wDeck[][FACES], const char *wFace[],
          const char *wSuit[] ){
    size_t card; //card counter
    size_t row; //row counter
    size_t column; //column counter

    //deal each of the cards
    for (card = 0; card <= CARDS; ++card){
        //loop through rows of wDeck
        for (row = 0; row < SUITS; ++row){
            //loop through columns in wDeck for current row
            for(column = 0; column < FACES; ++column){
                //if slot contians current card, display card
                if (wDeck[row][column] == card){
                    printf("%5s of %-8s%c", wFace[column], wSuit[row],
                           card % 2 == 0 ? '\n' : '\t'); //two column format
                } //end if
            } //end column for
        } //end row for
    } //end card for
} //end function deal

void dealHand(size_t wHands[][HAND], size_t wDeck[][FACES]){

    size_t cards;
    size_t players;
    unsigned int current;
    unsigned int current_suit;
    unsigned int current_face;

    for (cards = 0; cards <= HAND; cards ++){

        for (players = 0; players < PLAYERS; players++){
            current = cards * PLAYERS + players;
            current_suit = current / SUITS;
            current_face = current % FACES;
            wHands[players][cards] = wDeck[current_suit][current_face];
        } // end players for
    } // end cards for

} // end deal hand


//PRINT THE CARD
void printCard(unsigned int wCard, const char wFaces[FACES], const char wSuit[SUITS]){
    //find suit and face
    size_t suit;
    size_t face;

    suit = determineSuit(wCard);
    face = determineFace(wCard);

    printf("%s or %s", wFaces[face], wSuit[suit]);


} //end print card

//******************************
//BEGIN HAND TYPE DETERMINATION
//******************************


//find A PAIR
unsigned int findAPair(size_t wHand[HAND]){

    size_t countOfFaces[FACES] = { 0 };
    unsigned int foundAPair = 1;
    size_t card;


    for (card = 0; card < HAND; card++)
    {

        size_t face = determineFace(wHand[card]);

        countOfFaces[face]++;

        if (countOfFaces[face] == 3)
        {

            return 1;
        }
        else if (countOfFaces[face] == 2)
        {

            if (foundAPair)
            {

                return 1;
            }

            foundAPair = 0;
        }
    }
    return foundAPair;

} // end find a pair


//find TWO PAIRS
unsigned int findTwoPairs(size_t wHand[HAND]){

    size_t countOfFaces[FACES] = { 0 };

    unsigned int numberOfPairs = 0;

    size_t card;
    for (card = 0; card < HAND; card++){

        size_t face =  determineFace(wHand[card]);
        countOfFaces[face]++;

        if (countOfFaces[face] == 3)
        {

            return 1;
        }
        else if (countOfFaces[face] == 2)
        {

            numberOfPairs++;
        }
    }
    return numberOfPairs == 2;

} //end find two pairs


//find THREE OF A KIND
unsigned int findThreeOfAKind(size_t wHand[HAND]){

    size_t countOfFaces[FACES] = {0};
    size_t card;
    unsigned int foundThree = 1;

    for (card = 0; card < HAND; card++){
        size_t face = determineFace(wHand[card]);
        countOfFaces[face]++;

        if (countOfFaces[face] == 3){
            foundThree =  0;
        } //end if

        else if (countOfFaces[face] == 4){
            return 1;
        } //end else if

        else if (countOfFaces[face] == 2 && foundThree){
            return 1;
        } //end else if
    } //end card for loop

    return 1;

} //end find three of a kind



//find FOUR OF A KIND
unsigned int findFourOfAKind(size_t wHand[HAND]){

    size_t countOfFaces[FACES] = {0};
    size_t card;

    for (card = 0; card < HAND; card++){
        size_t face = determineFace(wHand[card]);
        countOfFaces[face]++;

        if (countOfFaces[face] == 4){
            return 0;
        } //end if
    } //end card for loop

    return 1;

} //end for of a kind

unsigned int findStraight (size_t wHand[HAND]){
    size_t card;

    size_t lowFace;
    size_t highFace;

    size_t firstSuit;
    unsigned int foundSecondSuit = 1;

    for (card = 0; card < HAND; card++)
    {
        size_t suit = determineSuit(wHand[card]);
        size_t face = determineFace(wHand[card]);

        // first card
        if (card == 0)
        {
            lowFace = face;
            highFace = face;

            firstSuit = suit;
        }
        // all other cards
        // check for two equal faces first
        else if (face == lowFace || face == highFace)
        {

            return 1;
        }
        // update low and high face, if necessary
        else
        {

            if (suit != firstSuit)
            {

                foundSecondSuit = 0;
            }

            // an Ace can only go low if the low face is at most a Five
            if (face == 0 && lowFace > HAND - 1)
            {

                face = 13;
            }
            if (face < lowFace)
            {

                lowFace = face;
            }

            if (face > highFace)
            {

                highFace = face;
            }

            if ((highFace - lowFace + 1) != HAND)
            {

                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return foundSecondSuit;
}


//find FLUSH
unsigned int findFlush(size_t wHand[HAND]){

    size_t card;
    size_t firstSuit = 5;
    for (card = 0; card < HAND; card++){
        size_t suit = determineSuit(wHand[card]);
        //determing if all cards are the same suit
        if (card == 0){
            firstSuit = suit;
        } //end if
        else if (suit != firstSuit){
            return 1;
        } //end else if
    } //end card for loop

    return 0;

} //end find flush



//find FULL HOUSE
unsigned int findFullHouse(size_t wHand[HAND]){
    if (findAPair(wHand) && findThreeOfAKind(wHand)){
        return 0;
    } //end if

    return 1;
} //end full house


//find STRAIGHT FLUSH
unsigned int findStraightFlush(size_t wHand[HAND]){

    size_t lowFace;
    size_t highFace;
    size_t card;
    size_t firstSuit;

    for (card = 0; card < HAND; card++){
        size_t suit = determineSuit(wHand[card]);
        size_t face = determineFace(wHand[card]);
        //determing if all cards are the same suit
        if (card == 0){
            firstSuit = suit;
            lowFace = face;
            highFace = face;
        } //end if
        else if (suit != firstSuit || face == lowFace || face == highFace){
            return 1;
        } //end else if

        //determination for ace being high or low, which depends on hand
        else
        {
            // an Ace can only go low if the low face is at most a Five
            if (face == 0 && lowFace > HAND - 1)
            {

                face = 13;
            }
            if (face < lowFace)
            {

                lowFace = face;
            }

            if (face > highFace)
            {

                highFace = face;
            }

            if ((highFace - lowFace + 1) != HAND)
            {

                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;

} //end straight flush

//****************************
//DETERMINING PLAYER OUTCOMES
//****************************

//determing PLAYER HAND
unsigned int determingPlayerHand(size_t wHand[HAND]){

    if (findStraightFlush(wHand) == 0){
        return 8;
    } //end if

    else if (findFourOfAKind(wHand) == 0){
        return 7;
    } //end else if

    else if (findFullHouse(wHand) == 0){
        return 6;
    } //end else if

    else if (findFlush(wHand) == 0){
        return 5;
    } //end else if

    else if (findStraight(wHand) == 0){
        return 4;
    } //end else if

    else if (findThreeOfAKind(wHand) == 0){
        return 3;
    } //end else if

    else if (findTwoPairs(wHand) == 0){
        return 2;
    } //end else if

    else if (findAPair(wHand) == 0){
        return 1;
    }


    return 0;

} //end determing player hand



//determing PLAYER RANK
void playerRank( size_t wHands[PLAYERS][HAND]){


    unsigned int player1 = determingPlayerHand(wHands);
    unsigned int player2 = determingPlayerHand(wHands);

    if (player1 > player2){
        printf("%s", "Player 1 Wins!");
    }//end if

    else if (player2 > player1){
        printf("%s", "Player 2 Wins!");
    }

} //end player rank
```

I'm loathe to post this, but sadly, I've got to finish this by tomorrow and I've already been working on it 12 hours straight.  My concern is that I set up my poker hand type function to only take one dimension of the two dimensional array.  Is there a way to effectively build a ranking system for players with what I have?

Here are some notes I made to myself elsewhere that may also be useful:  determingPlayerHand only takes one subscript of the two dimensional array.  I need playerRanking to take both subscripts.  How can I make this happen so that my rankings will return properly to each player? The ranking returning values should be fine, I think. I initially had it as just true or false, 1 or 0, but then realized that wasn't specific enough

Please let me know what other information I can provide if I need to make this more clear or relevant.

After M Oehm's comment,  I want to update this to reflect some other information that I realized would be useful.

Part of the parameters of the problem I'm solving require certain things to be the way they are.  If I had my choice in changing them, I think there are better ways to do this as well.  However, the deck being as it is, the shuffling algorithm, and the deal algorithm are built to specification of the problem.  As for hands evaluating to what they should, so far they do, and I wrote it based on the idea that ace needs to go high at a certain point, which is part of why it's so complicated.  The two dimensional array with [PLAYERS][HAND] is meant to make it so that cards are dealt in alternating order to each player from the top of the deck, as would be done in real life.

Comment: `long time user of stack overflow, new time poster.`...does not look like that,,,,

Answer (score 2):

You have gotten off to a bad start when chosing how to represent your deck and the hands.

You represent the cards as integers from 0 to 51 in the deck's factory order from Ace of Hearts to King of Clubs. That's fine. You can determine the rank and suit from the card number:

```
rank = card % 13;
suit = card / 13;
```

That's not what you do in your `determineFace`/`Suit` functions. Next, the deck ist a one-dimensional array of cards:

```
int deck[52];
```

You can shuffle this array with one of the well-known shuffling algorithms, e.g. Fisher-Yates. You represent the deck as two-dimensional array, which doesn't make the shuffling any easier. It it also not clear what the two dimensions of the deck are. (Okay, they are suit and rank, but after shuffling, that doesn't make sense any longer.)

In a one-dimensional array, the first player's hand are the first five cards and the second player's hand are cards 5 to 9.

Your algorithms to determine the hands are too complicated and have some copy-and-paste errors. Evaluating poker hands boils down to three criteria:

- **Flush**: Are all cards of a hand of the same suit?
- **Straight**: Are all ranks consecutive? (With the special rule that the ace can be played high or lowas appropriate)
- **Multiples**: Most hands have pairs, triplets or quadruplets of cards or combinations thereof, so you need a "histogram" of ranks, sorted by occurrence.

With that data, you can determine your hands. You also need secondary data to distinguish between two equal hands, e.g. a pair of Kings and a pair of Nines.

I suggest you start afresh, switch on compiler warnings and implement shuffling, dealing and the three hand criteria step by step with verification between the steps. (You can call these steps "Milestones", if you like.)

Comment: Thank you for the initial info and questions.  I've updated the post to answer some of those.  I appreciate your thoughts.